# TFS2010: Fast way to determine user, who edited "this function" or "this line of code"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

we use TFS controlled source. Are there a fast way to determine the history of a function I'm currently in - like anwsering "who edited this function?" or "who edited this line of code?".
I know, that I can open source control for the current file and browse the history to find a changeset, where the lines of code / the function I'm interested in were edited.

But I'm looking for an easier way ... may be any addons for Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks, Konrad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the annotate option.

This is available from most of the Source Control options in TFS. I normally invoke it from the Source Code context menu of the Code Editor windows, but it's also in:

- Source Control Explorer context menu for Files.
- "Source Control - Team Foundation Server" toobar.
- "File" -> "Source Control" menu.

The Annotation will show which changeset is responsible for each line/block of code. You can see which user checked in a changeset. Sometimes you have to filter the changeset range if the file has been merged by an innocent person.

**Annotated File**

[image: Annoted File]

Comment: Ah, you fleshed it out now ;)

Comment: Yes, I answered on my phone whilst my PC rebooted :)

Comment: Perfect ... exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

As DaveShaw says.  Right-click on the line you're interested in, select the last option 'Source Control' and choose 'Annotate'.

This will give you a list of who made edits and when in the file, down the left-hand side of the code-editor pane.